# GCDWebServer, when POST, request.query is nil

Tags: gcdwebserver

use GCDWebServer, when method is GET, NSLog request.query is the parameter dictionary I passed, that is want I want. But when is POST, request.query is nil?  why? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `query` property is only for the query in the URL, not within the POST body.

For a typical POST form, you will want to use the `GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest` class and then the `arguments` property to access the data.

See the README for an example and the headers for more information.